# Updating Index & Match values by using Variant Arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, indexing, variant

My code works and executes exactly what I need it to do, but I would like to improve it's processing time as updating each individual cell is significantly slowing down my macro.

Currently, I am using VBA to do an Index & Match formula with another workbook where it retrieves information (parameters) from. I believe the slow processing time is because I'm updating the values in each individual cell using Index and Match by using a `Range`. I would like to **mass load Variant arrays** instead but I am struggling with incorporating it within my code and adjusting it.

Here is my current code without any Variant Arrays:

```
'This macro uses an Index and Match application to fill in the "Changes Pending Approval" parameters in the "Operator" worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()                                                                   'Occurs after the worksheet is recalculated for the Worksheet object (any changes in the intersect cell)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                                                  'This speeds up the macro by hiding what the macro is doing

If Not Intersect(Range("H4"), Range("H4")) Is Nothing Then                                          'Checking if the "Key" (part or process) has been changed

Dim yChanges As Worksheet, OperatorWs As Worksheet                                                  'Declaring worksheets as variables
Dim yChangesLastRow As Long, Parameters As Long, x As Long, z As Long                               'Declaring variables to count last rows and "x" & "z" as integers (long variables)

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\Databases\Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm", Password:="123")  'Sets the Workbook variable as the database filepath
Set yChanges = y.Sheets("Changes")                                                                  'Sets the Worksheet variable as the "Changes" sheet in the database's workbook
Set OperatorWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Operator")                                                'Sets the Worksheet variable as the "Operator" sheet in this workbook
OperatorWs.Unprotect "123"                                                                        'Unprotects the "Operator" sheet

Parameters = yChanges.Range("F1:CL1").Columns.Count                                                 'Counts the number of columns in the "Changes" sheet

yChangesLastRow = yChanges.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                                    'Finds the last row in the "Changes" sheet & counts the number of rows

yChangesLastRow = yChangesLastRow - 2                                                               '-2 from the number of rows to account for the header & Vlookup (2nd) column

z = 6                                                                                               'Sets variable "z" to start with the first parameter in the "Changes" sheet (Column "F")

    For x = 31 To Parameters + 31                                                                   'Sets variable "x" to start from the first Parameter in the "Operator" sheet to the last row

        With yChanges                                                                               'With the "Changes" sheet do the following

            Dim IndexRng As Range                                                                   'Declaring variable as a range
            Set IndexRng = .Range(.Cells(3, z), .Cells(yChangesLastRow, z))                         'Sets range variable as the index lookup array (Pending Changes entries)

            Dim MatchRng As Range                                                                   'Declaring variable as a range
            Set MatchRng = .Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow)                                         'Sets range variable as the match lookup array (Pending changes "Keys" only)

        End With                                                                                    'Ending the "With statement"

    Dim matchNum As Variant                                                                         'Declaring variable as general datatype
    matchNum = Application.Match(Sheet1.Range("H4").Value, MatchRng, 0)                             'Sets variable equal to the Match function to find the "Key" in the "Changes" sheet

                If Not IsError(matchNum) Then                                                       'Checking if the "Key" is in the "Changes" sheet (True or False)

                    OperatorWs.Range("N" & x).Value = Application.Index(IndexRng, matchNum)         'True: Sets the Changes Pending Approval parameters in the "Operator" sheet

                Else                                                                                'False: no match was found for the "Key" (Part & Process) in the "Changes sheet

                    Exit Sub                                                                        'End the macro

                End If                                                                              'End the "IF" statement
    
    z = z + 1                                                                                       '+1 to execute the "For" statement with the next (lookup) parameter

    Next x                                                                                          'Executes the "For" statement with the next "x" value (+1 until it reaches the "Parameters + 31" integer)

OperatorWs.Protect "123"                                                                          'Protect the "Operator" sheet
    
y.Save                                                                                              'Save the database Workbook

y.Close False                                                                                       'Close the database Workbook

End If                                                                                              'End the "IF" statement

Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                                                   'Must be "True" after running the code to be able to Read/Write the Workbook

End Sub                                                                                             'End the macro
```

Comment: Match is slower with arrays than with ranges, btw.

Comment: @BigBen what is an alternative to using ranges (other than mass loading variant arrays) for index & match to increase the speed because it's quite slow for me right now; also I was using this as a reference for the performance ratios https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: To clarify my comment - `Match` can be used against a range (as you are currently doing) or against an array. It is slower if used against an array. I assume the answer to your question will load the data into an array and loop, instead of using `Match`.

Comment: @BigBen Yes I'm currently working on looping my data inside the array but struggling with it

Comment: You're right reading and manipulating values in memory will certainly speed up your code. However, the main reason your code is particularly slow is the choice of the event handler. Do you really need it to be triggered in `Worksheet_Calculate`? You will see a significant improvement by adding `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the top of your procedure and resetting it at the bottom using `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`. Just imagine, every time you change a cell in the loop, the code starts running from the beginning, again and again and again and ...

Comment: I would actually remove the lines I suggested above and replace them with `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top and reset it at the bottom with `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: @Supersymmetry Thank you for the suggestions, I have now added ```Application.ScreenUpdating = False```, ```Application.DisplayStatusBar = False```, ```Application.EnableEvents = False```, ```Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual``` at the top of my code below ```Worksheet_Calculate``` and at the bottom of my code ```Application.ScreenUpdating = True```, ```Application.DisplayStatusBar = True```, ```Application.EnableEvents = True```, ```Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic```

Comment: Did it make a significat difference? or do you still need further optimisation?

Comment: Just be careful with `xlCalculationManual`: sometimes the flow of your program may depend on values calculated by cell formulae, and therefore, this can lead to a bug that's difficult to find in the future. `DisplayStatsusBar` will only remove any message from the status bar, it doesn't really optimise anything. I personally would stick with `ScreenUpdating` and `EnableEvents`, but it's your call.

Comment: @Supersymmetry I left out the ```DisplayStatusBar``` as it really made no significant impact and was visually distracting anyhow. But ```Screenupdating``` and ```EnableEvents``` together seem to have a good impact on the speed, but unfortunately I still require further optimization